# Solving an error in matlab code

Tags: matlab

I am having this error in Matlab (R2009a) and I try to find a solution for it with no success, this error shouldn´t exist since I am using a source code that I downloaded hence it should be working fine.
Any idea why is not working?

Error message:

> ??? Undefined function or method 'fittype' for input arguments of type
>   'char'.
>
> Error in ==> ChIPnorm at 132 ft_ = fittype('smoothingspline');

Thank you!

Comment: can you post the definition of your 'fittype' function? without that we'll be stabbing in the dark...

Comment: the "fittype" is in Matlab curve fitting toolbox.  (http://www.mathworks.se/help/curvefit/fittype.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you didn't install the Curve Fitting Toolbox.
Or maybe the function was added *after* R2009a (I could not check the documentation for that version, but I can tell you on R2010a is available).